# how to add new members in Struct in c++

Tags: struct

This is my struct :

```
struct info {
char[100][20] username;
char[100][20] password;

}users[1000];
```

I want to add an option in menu to ask admin to add new columns like `email`,`phonenmuber`,`location` etc in this struct

How can i add them ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, changing the contents of a `struct` requires that you change the source code of the program and recompile it. If you want an admin to be able to change the types of information stored per user without recompiling the program, you're going to have to do something more elaborate than just a `struct`.